# VScode Javascript Breakpoints are ignored by Chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I know there is a ton of "similar" questions, but being similar doesn't mean they are the same, if they were the same, they wouldn't exist, I haven't found the answer I'm looking for.

It must be something simple, as in other projects of mine it does work. 
There is a difference in behavior:

-**other projects that work**: When I click on the bottom-left 'launch chrome against localhost(testApp)' and then I click 'launch chrome against localhost' on the top menu (which is redundant and stupid) Chrome opens and returns instantly to the first breakpoint.

-**on this project** Chrome opens displaying the file list in the working directory via localhost. Then, when I select the html file the js code runs ignoring the breakpoints. Go figure...

Comment: [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome#troubleshooting) - try to put your javascript in a .js file, that may help.

Comment: I always have it in a .js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What 'confused' VScode 'Debugger for Chrome' extension is that I had named the html file with the name of my project (eg myproject.html) When I renamed it as 'index.html' it stopped displaying the working folder contents but instead of returning to the VScode breakpoint, the breakpoint turned to the following icon:
[unverified  breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjEws.png)

When I put the "main.js" file inside a 'src' folder and updated the path in the html file, everything worked. That is more Sherlock Holmes investigation than programming. About 3 hours were wasted...